# Range to Array getting gummed up somehow in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am looking to copy a range into an array. The range is two columns and unknown rows.

This code works perfectly in a fresh workbook but not in my big complicated workbook.

What could be going wrong? in the complicated workbook, the below code shows the correct number of message boxes (and LastRow is right) but blanks for the array values.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim pN() As Variant
    Dim LastRow As Integer

    With Worksheets("merp")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        ReDim pN(1 To LastRow, 1 To 2)
        pN = .Range("A1:B" & LastRow).Value

        MsgBox LastRow

        For i = 1 To LastRow
            MsgBox CStr(pN(i, 1)) & " and " & CStr(pN(i, 2))
        Next

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Without a [mcve], I don't see how your question can be answered since the answer seems to depend on things that you have not told us about (the structure of this mysterious "big complicated workbook", as well as presumably some other code). The code that you posted works for me when I mock up an example. (Not your problem -- but it would be better to use `Long` than `Integer` and would be better to use `Option Explicit` to force yourself to declare variables. `i` is nowhere declared.)

Comment: Thank you John. The workbook has about thirty different macros I've written, though none of them should influence the code in question, so I wasn't sure how to disclose them. I have just sort of given up and resorted to pasting the range into the worksheet and referencing the pasted cells vs storing it in an array and referencing that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Button1_Click()
        Dim pN As Variant, i As Long
        Dim LastRow As Long

        With Worksheets("merp")
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            pN = .Range("A1:B" & LastRow).value
            MsgBox LastRow

            For i = 1 To LastRow
                MsgBox CStr(pN(i, 1)) & " and " & CStr(pN(i, 2))
            Next
        End With
End Sub
```

It should work if your "complicated workbook" does not have merged cells in that specific range...

Comment: This code is (more or less) functionally equivalent to OP's code, so it is likely to fail for whatever unknown reason their original code is failing. Having said that, this code is of course a more idiomatic way of doing what they are trying to do.